# SONAR 3.7.3 setup for .net project. MOQ code coverage

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, code-analysis, sonar-runner

I am doing a POC for .Net projects by using SONAR. 
My 1st attempt is to only evaluate the code coverage of my Mock tests. 
So far I have installed in my sandbox (Win7) the below apps:

- SONAR 3.7.3
- SONAR RUNNER 2.3

My sonar website is hosted in the default url **localhost:9000** and I am able to see on the browser. 
I have created a  sonar-project.propeties file under the same folder where my sln file is
My sonar-project.propeties looks like this:

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=my:project
sonar.projectName=My project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=cs
```

My problem comes when I execute the sonar-runner on the sane folder, which throws the below error message:

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.767s
Final Memory: 5M/20M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknow
n': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with t
he -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Any idea what might be causing this?
I believe that I am not missing nothing.

### Additonal Infomation

When I execute the sonar-runner with the flag -e i get the below message:

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 20.841s
Final Memory: 12M/110M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher
.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102
)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Error while reading Gendarme resu
lt file: C:\Users\a-jose.valdes\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PoC\NAFT
.PoC.Implementation\.sonar\gendarme-report.xml
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.gendarme.results.GendarmeResultParser.parse(
GendarmeResultParser.java:105)
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.gendarme.GendarmeSensor.analyseResults(Genda
rmeSensor.java:226)
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.gendarme.GendarmeSensor.analyse(GendarmeSens
or.java:182)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:7
2)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:114)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanConta
iner.java:142)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentCo
ntainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.
java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.j
ava:187)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScan
Container.java:182)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScan
Container.java:180)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanCon
tainer.java:175)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentCo
ntainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.
java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.ja
va:82)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentCo
ntainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.
java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapCon
tainer.java:156)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapCo
ntainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentCo
ntainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.
java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java
:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher
.java:87)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Unexpected first character (char co
de 0xEF), not valid in xml document: could be mangled UTF-8 BOM marker. Make sur
e that the Reader uses correct encoding or pass an InputStream instead
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderBootstrapper.bootstrapInput(ReaderBootstrapper.
java:174)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:5
31)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:585
)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:641
)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFac
tory.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.staxmate.SMInputFactory.createStax2Reader(SMInputFactory
.java:234)
        at org.codehaus.staxmate.SMInputFactory.rootElementCursor(SMInputFactory
.java:337)
        at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.gendarme.results.GendarmeResultParser.parse(
GendarmeResultParser.java:100)
        ... 39 more
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: What command line are you using to trigger the Sonar runner?

Comment: I have executed sonar-runner under the root folder of my solution + sonar-project.properties file
I also tried to use the sonar-runner -e and it throws a bunch of information.
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.project Version, sonar.sources

Comment: It really looks like the SonarQube Runner is not executed from the directory containing the  sonar-project.properties file or that the sonar-project.properties file is misspelled. Could you please provide the full stack trace to know the answer?

Comment: Could you please provide the full command line that you are using to launch the Sonar runner?

Comment: I have added more information on the question, I'll hope this can help.

Comment: I have found my first issue. My File properties was misspelled. 
So I have corrected this.
However I still get error. I will replace the stack trace with the newest.

Comment: At this moment I do not have installed FxCop App, Gendarme and StyleCop Plugins. Should I?

Comment: Does the INFO say: INFO: Project configuration file: NONE. If so. Check your naming of the properties file. In your post you write ".propeties" with a missing 'r'. Correct spelling: sonar-project.properties. One of your INFO lines SHOULD display the full path to your properties file like mine here: "INFO: Project configuration file: c:\temp\ConsoleApplication13\sonar-project.properties"

Answer (score 2):

Based on this message in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Unexpected first character (char co
de 0xEF), not valid in xml document: could be mangled UTF-8 BOM marker. Make sur
e that the Reader uses correct encoding or pass an InputStream instead
```

I would suggest setting this property in either your `sonar-project.properties` file or in the `sonar-runner.properties` file:

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```